# Нужно прописать <receiver> в манифесте

Tags: android, android-manifest

Делаю уведомления, появляющиеся в определенное время. Есть класс, который нужно прописать в манифесте(надеюсь, что только поэтому не работает), но я не до конца понимаю, как это правильно сделать. Вот например:

```
<receiver android:name=".WiFiStatusReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">

                               <intent-filter>

                                           <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE"/>

                               </intent-filter>

                    </receiver>
```

Откуда брать action?.. На всякий случай код из MainActivity

```
Calendar notifyTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    notifyTime.set(2018,5,30,20,10);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                                                             intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notifyTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

И класс, который нужно прописать:

```
package com.example.alexadra.alarm;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                "До меня добрались!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        // Запускаем уведомление
        AlarmNotification.notify(context,"Eee",5);
    }
}
```